# Rails server LoadError Symbol not found: _environ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I'm using jruby and trying to run a Rails app. This app worked well before I `rvm use jruby` 'd. I need to use jruby, because I'm using the gem neo4j, which requires jruby.

All gems worked well with jruby, except `pg`. After struggling for hours to get rid of the `Postgresql Client Library not found` error, I finally got a clean output from `bundle install`

However, now the server won't start. It gives me [this](http://pastebin.com/P3cxKZjw) error, the gist of which is:

```
LoadError: load error: pg_ext -- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(~/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _environ
```

[This](http://pastebin.com/LiZzX0mK) is what I have in my Gemfile [output of `bundle install`]

Update: As suggested by vvlad, I tried out activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter, which worked for me. However, the webserver gem 'thin' now gives an [error](http://pastebin.com/VmVUyMcy)

Comment: did you try to use activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter gem instead of pg? It uses a jdbc adapter for postgress which is kind of a standard in java world

Comment: Hmm.. I'll test that out. Hopefully it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: The gem you mentioned works. However, I get a similar, but slightly different error now!

http://pastebin.com/VmVUyMcy